# Is there a shortcut for opening a terminal in the current folder in Thunar?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunar

Is there a shortcut for opening a terminal in the current folder in Thunar? This can be done by right clicking, but is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/403922/keyboard-shortcut-for-thunar-custom-actions

Answer (score 1):

You could use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and then the arrow keys to open the terminal.

Comment: This at least works for my Linux distro.