# How do i add a shortcut to open terminal in that folder Thunar

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunar

Thunar does show terminal option when right clinking inside a folder but i want to specify a shortcut(super shift E) to open terminal in the folder that is open

is that possible?
if so how do i do that?

the following question and my question aren't the same
[Is there a shortcut for opening a terminal in the current folder in Thunar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234567/is-there-a-shortcut-for-opening-a-terminal-in-the-current-folder-in-thunar)

Answer (score 2):

Thunar has Custom actions you can specify your shortcuts there

go to edit> custom actions > double click terminal > specify your keyboard shortcut there

you can learn more about custom shortcuts [here](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/4.16/custom-actions)